# Communicating with another terminal application via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'll start off by saying I'm no Linux guru, or even close. I use it to develop embedded applications and it serves my purposes just fine as such.

I have a program which is running (I suppose the correct terminology is "running in a terminal") on a CentOS 6.3 box. For debug and statistics, I have a routine which monitors the keyboard (stdin file) and spits out items as requested by the given key-presses. That all works fine when I'm sitting in front of it.

But I'd like to be able to perform these simple functions: press a key, see some output, remotely. I can SSH into the box and execute commands, but I can't "see" this program.

I have tried searching "communicating with other terminals using ssh" and myriad variations, but I guess I'm not asking this correctly -- the search results are worthless.

What I'd like to be able to do is login to my account and then somehow "see" my program running and type keys and see its output. Is this a stdin/stdout redirection issue?

I apologize in advance if this is painfully obvious and I'm just an idiot, but I'd still like to know how to do it... :)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but have you used screen or tmux?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on 'screen' !!

Comment: If screen is the solution, note that you could also have opened a second ssh terminal.. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what that *exactly* means. Being more wrapped up in the application, I have not had the time to dive into Linux in the manner I would've liked to. I used Unix in College, but quickly got involved in the embedded world. I ended up using TMUX. But if what you're saying is that I don't really need SCREEN or TMUX, I would very much appreciate it if you have the time to elaborate. So far I have a TMUX session which I attach to after logging in via SSH. If there's a way for me to not add more running code and use an existing feature more effectively, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the linux 'screen' utility, you can re-attach to the original terminal session that you used to start the program. basically you just type screen and then run your program. here is more useful info on screen:

http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to